# Inappbrowser download a file in the browser

Tags: javascript, file, cordova, inappbrowser

is it possible to download a file in the inappbrowser? 
[image]

This my simple web programm. i open it in my inappbrowser and will download a file after click the download button. But atm notting happends..

```
function startWrapper(result) {
    iabRef = window.open(result, "_blank", 'location=no');
    iabRef.addEventListener('loadstart', iabLoadStart);
    iabRef.addEventListener('loadstop', iabLoadStop);
    iabRef.removeEventListener('loaderror', iabLoadError);
    iabRef.addEventListener('exit', iabClose);
}
```

Is it possible and how?

Comment: inappbrowser just open the url which you are passing. so if you did download coding in your webpage, it will download

Comment: But i doesn't happen?! The download button works in the normal browser. But not in the inappbrowser..

Comment: it may be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652554/phonegap-cordova-inappbrowser-file-download-issue